# How to check the coming output from main method?

Tags: java, testing, output, program-entry-point

For example, with the following main method.

```
public class Solution {
   public static void main(String []argv)   {
       System.out.println("Hello World.");
       System.out.println("Hello Java.");
   }
}
```

I want to know how code a platform (Hackerrank, for example) would check that the main method prints the expected output.

```
Hello World.
Hello Java.
```

Is not easy imagine how to do it with Junit, at first sight.
I believe that an external program is checking the output, I mean something like this:

```
$ java Solution | runtests
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess using unix pipe-lining is certainly a way that it could be done.

In Java, you could do it by running the `java` command and reading the output through an `InputStream`

```
// Create and start the process
Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Solution").start();
// Create a reader to read in each output line
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
String line;
// Read in line by line
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the `start()` method of `ProcessBuilder` can throw an `IOException`, so you will need to account for that.

Comment: I thought of using a `ProcessBuilder` as well, but actually for calling Java code, the best way is most likely to call it directly, isn't it ?

Comment: @Dici Yeah, calling it directly is probably the best way, as long as you're not worried about the written code interfering with the code that runs it of course (code run through a separate process will be in its own environment).

Comment: Yep, your solution would span a new JVM. That could be a good thing for isolation purposes, but I wonder if it is sustainable for a server that would receive lots of solutions to assess. Maybe it's just fine, maybe it isn't, although I can see why having two solutions running on the same JVM can be pretty bad... +1

Comment: @Dici Good point about the massive computational load that would come with spawning a lot of JVMs when under heavy usage.

Comment: Yes but in all fairness it might be the right thing to do. Websites such as Codility assess solutions on their performance, and the result can affect a hiring decision so they better not think a solution is slower than it really is just because it can in the same JVM as a crazy slow solution. The isolation might well be necessary here.

Comment: Just in case someone stumble upon this, the solution to make it work in the same JVM depends on creating a new *isolated* classloader, that is re-creating at runtime a classpath that fits the purpose. You will have to decide which parts the host code is needed in the new classloader to garanty interoperability between the two "worlds".
(Meaning the same class loaded twice by distinct classloaders will not be compatible)